# webview in react native when click on any link in website which open in new tab or new window its goes to browser not override on the webview

Tags: reactjs, webview, native

In React native WebView , In webview there was a problem occur when click on link which open in new tap or new window ,the webview redirect our app to the browser but I want app not redirect to browser the webview override the link . Please solve the problem , I am very thinkful to you....

when click on any link in the website theses website redirect to our browser from our react native app

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const App = () =>{

return(
<WebView
 source={{uri:"https://www.coeju.com"}}

 />
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Please add the current code snippet as well to see and understand the problem better.

Answer (score 6):

setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
add this in your webview props.
For more to know how this works, visit below link.

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#setsupportmultiplewindows

```js
<WebView
  {...restProps}
  source={{uri}}
  onLoadStart={()=>setloading(true)}
  onLoadEnd={()=>setloading(false)}
  onLoad={()=>setloading(false)}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  injectedJavaScript={INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT}
  scrollEnabled
  setSupportMultipleWindows={false} //This will solve your problem
>
```

Comment: From the docs: 'Setting this to false can expose the application to this vulnerability allowing a malicious iframe to escape into the top layer DOM.' (https://alesandroortiz.com/articles/uxss-android-webview-cve-2020-6506/)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you can prevent the webview to redirect to an external browser and capture the URL that has been pressed and replace the current URI by storing it in the state.

you can try using  the **onShouldStartLoadWithRequest** props of webview

```
const[uri,seturi]=useState('https://stackoverflow.com/')

<WebView
 source={{uri}}
 onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={request => {
  if (request.url.includes('https')) {
      seturi(request.url);
      return false;
  } else return true;
 }}
 />
```

Comment: yes , how to get this property in webview in react native please share code

Comment: how to get or fetch  those url or link which redirect you to browser in the webview in the react native . I wonder many days but not get solution please help.